# Getting a 'Cannot resolve method' error

Tags: javascript, java, android, variables

I am getting an error in the code below. The error is 'Cannot resolve method 'getApplication()' '
Any help? I think it is because of the way I am pulling my global variable. Maybe a better way to set the variable.

```js
public class game_select extends Activity {



  protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {


    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.game_select);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


      public void onClick(View v) {

        // Perform action on click
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Global_variables) this.getApplication()).setGameselected("http://vector-runner-remix.tresensa.com/index.html?dst=B0000");
      }


    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "this" refers to the onClickListener

Do this:

```
((Global_variables) game_select.this.getApplication()).setGameselected("http://vector-runner-remix.tresensa.com/index.html?dst=B0000");
```

The "this" this time refers to your activity class

Comment: Alright so now I can run my game, but it crashes when I click the button.

Comment: Hi, that would already another problem question :), I only answered your current unresolved method problem. You may raise a new question for the crash. Ahoy

Comment: Hmm. For your next questions, If you find the answers satisfying for the question, you should give them what they deserve :). Thanks

Comment: If you meant accepting the answer I have done that. Though I am new to this forum so I apologize I have forgotten something.